# Failed Download Error While Using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

My script downloads a PDF file, but when it downloads, it says "Failed - Download Error".

When I do everything manually, it works fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import os
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import urllib.request

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option(

    'prefs',
    {
        "download.default_directory":"C:/Users/my.username/Desktop",
        "download.prompt_for_download":False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True

    }
)
    

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path = 'C:/Users/my.username/Downloads/chromdriver_v100/chromedriver.exe'
    ,chrome_options = options
    )
   
driver.get('https://www.mywebsite/users/sign_in')


WebElement_username = driver.find_element_by_name("user[login]")
WebElement_username.send_keys("my_username")


WebElement_password = driver.find_element_by_name("user[password]")
WebElement_password.send_keys("my_password")

WebElement_password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/company/123/facility/58965/reports/close_of_day/2022-4-1/2022-4-20.pdf'

driver.get(url)
```

Is there something else I need to do differently?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Here is some useful documentation:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8871110/failed-download-error-since-chrome-version-75-0-3770-100-official-build-64-bit?hl=en

I needed to change:

```
"download.default_directory":"C:/Users/my.username/Desktop",
```

to

```
"download.default_directory":"C:\Users\my.username\Desktop",
```